# ipynb is not saving cell output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

When I return to a [notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) I have run and saved previously, I cannot write and run new cells that reference previously declared variables without rerunning the rest of the notebook. Even in a cell with all new variables, I am given a missing import error unless I rerun the imports cell. I am using a local [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment instead of the Jupyter kernel, and coworkers, using the same environment, do not have the same issue.

```python
#Cell 1
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
x, y = i, j
```

```python
#Cell 2
print(x, y)
```

After running Cell 1, I should be able to run cell 2 without error after saving and quitting, but I am forced rerun Cell 2. This would not be an issue, but for the fact that some of my cells take at least 10 minutes to run.